# Bubble sort algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, reinventing-the-wheel

I'm starting to implement basic sorting algorithms. Criticisms on the implementation is welcome.

```
#import pudb; pu.db
def bubble_sort(list_):
    """Implement bubblesort algorithm: iterate L to R in list, switching values
    if Left > Right. Break when no alterations made to to list. """
    not_complete = True
    while not_complete:
        not_complete = False
        for val, item in enumerate(list_):
            if val == len(list_)-1: val = 0
            else:
                if list_[val] > list_[val+1]:
                    list_[val], list_[val+1] = list_[val+1], list_[val]
                    not_complete = True
    return list_

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert bubble_sort(list(range(9))[::-1]) == list(range(9))
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. This line seems to be left over from a debugging session:

   ```
   #import pudb; pu.db
   ```

   But there is no need to edit your code to debug it — and you should strive to avoid doing so, because it's too easy to forget to remove the debugging code. (And [in your other question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/40734/11728) you did forget to remove it!)

   Instead, learn how to use the tools. You can run the built-in debugger [`pdb`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) from the command line like this:

   ```
   $ python -mpdb myprogram.py
   ```

   and you can run `pudb` from the command line [as described in the documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pudb).
2. The docstring is written from the wrong point of view:

   ```
   """Implement bubblesort algorithm: iterate L to R in list, switching values
   if Left > Right. Break when no alterations made to to list. """
   ```

   Docstrings should be written from the *user's* point of view: What does this function do? How should I call it? What values does it return? What side effects does it have? For example:

   ```
   >>> help(abs)
   Help on built-in function abs in module builtins:

   abs(...)
       abs(number) -> number

       Return the absolute value of the argument.
   ```

   Your docstring is written from the point of view of the *implementer*. This kind of material should be in comments.
3. You spelled your variable `list_` to avoid shadowing the built-in function `list`. I would prefer to find a better name for the variable rather than arbitrarily respelling it like this. Since your algorithm works on any [*mutable sequence*](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) (not just lists), then `seq` might be a good name.
4. Instead of:

   ```
   else:
       if condition:
           code
   ```

   write:

   ```
   elif condition:
       code
   ```
5. You have a special case:

   ```
   if val == len(list_)-1: val = 0
   ```

   to ensure that `val + 1` does not run off the end of the list. But it would be better to stop the iteration before that happens. So instead of:

   ```
   for val, item in enumerate(list_):
   ```

   write:

   ```
   for val in range(len(list_) - 1):
   ```
6. `val` is an index into the list: it's conventional to give such variables names like `i` and `j`.
7. Each time around the `while not_complete` loop, you make a pass over the whole of the sequence. But there is an easy optimization, [noted by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Optimizing_bubble_sort):

   > The bubble sort algorithm can be easily optimized by observing that the n-th pass finds the n-th largest element and puts it into its final place. So, the inner loop can avoid looking at the last n-1 items when running for the n-th time.

   So I would write it like this:

   ```
   def bubble_sort(seq):
       """Sort the mutable sequence seq in place and return it."""
       for i in reversed(range(len(seq))):
           finished = True
           for j in range(i):
               if seq[j] > seq[j + 1]:
                   seq[j], seq[j + 1] = seq[j + 1], seq[j]
                   finished = False
           if finished:
               break
       return seq
   ```
8. You have some test code at the end of the script. It is best to organize test code like this into *unit tests* using the [`unittest`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) module. For example:

   ```
   from unittest import TestCase
   from random import random

   class BubbleSortTest(TestCase):
       def test_bubble_sort(self):
           seq = [random() for _ in range(4000)]
           sorted_seq = sorted(seq)
           self.assertEqual(bubble_sort(seq), sorted_seq)
   ```

   Note how I've used randomization to get a wider range of test cases. (I've also made the length of the test array large enough to give a noticeable delay and so emphasize how poor an algorithm bubble sort is.)

Answer (score 7):

> ```
> for val, item in enumerate(list_):
> ```

You don't use `item`, so don't get it. Instead, use `xrange(len(list_))`

> ```
> if val == len(list_)-1: val = 0
> ```

This rechecks position 0 again. There is no need to do that. Instead, change the loop so it goes one less round.

Answer (score 0):

```
def swap(mylist,i):
    temp1 = mylist[i]                  
    temp2 = mylist[i+1]
    mylist[i] = temp2
    mylist[i+1] = temp1

def one_scan(mylist):
    for i in range (len(mylist)-1): 
        if(mylist[i] >= mylist[i+1]):
            swap(mylist,i)

def sortMyL(L):
    i = 0
    while(i<len(L)):
        one_scan(L)
        i+=1
    print("Sorted list")
    print(L)
```

Let's say x = [3,2,1,6,7]

`sortMyL(x)` will print out [1,2,3,6,7]

Feel free to ask any questions.